# List Comprehension Behavior with a CSV Object

Tags: python, csv, list-comprehension, python-2.6

I'm trying to construct two simple lists from a CSV object in Python 2.6.  In all of my tests, the second generated lists always returns as empty (the first generated list returns just fine.) It's almost as if the second list comprehension is starting before the first one is finished. The only way that I can get this code to run as expected is to copy the CSV data into its own list, and then iterate the copy--which is fine, but seems inefficient.

I'm stumped.

The suspect code:

```
import csv

data_source = '/charts.csv'
final_data = []
x_obs1 = []
y_obs1 = []
x_obs2 = []
y_obs2 = []

data_file = open(data_source, "r")
final_data = csv.reader(data_file, delimiter=',')

[(x_obs1.append(item[0]), y_obs1.append(item[1])) for item in final_data]
[(x_obs2.append(item[0]), y_obs2.append(item[2])) for item in final_data]

data_file.close()

print y_obs2
```

Returns: `[]`

This works as expected:

```
import csv

data_source = '/charts.csv'
final_data = []
x_obs1 = []
y_obs1 = []
x_obs2 = []
y_obs2 = []

data_file = open(data_source, "r")
csv_data = csv.reader(data_file, delimiter=',')

[final_data.append(item) for item in csv_data]

data_file.close()

[(x_obs1.append(item[0]), y_obs1.append(item[1])) for item in final_data]
[(x_obs2.append(item[0]), y_obs2.append(item[2])) for item in final_data]

print y_obs2
```

Returns: `['Barometric Pressure Normal', '30', '30', '30', '30', '30'....`

What am I missing? Any insight would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, `csv.reader` is good for one go through the csv file only. The second time you try and iterate over the same `csv.reader`, it has already been exhausted, so returns an empty list.

So your second case is the more correct way of doing what you need. It creates a cached copy of the CSV data without the need to go back through the file on disk (which is comparatively expensive).

Comment: Beautiful.  I had no idea that the csv.reader object was good for one go and would be exhausted.  Where were you yesterday?  Thanks very much!

Comment: You're very welcome! I've spent many hours scratching my head at similar issues, so really glad to help ;)